# CPU limit queueable job

Tags: apex, trigger, queueable-interface

I have a scenario where I'm inserting large number of records through trigger --> queueable job and running in to CPU timeout exception. 
I believe the best way of overcoming this is to split records in queueable and call the same job recursively.However, I'm not sure on how on to implement this

```
public class InsertnewRecords implements Queueable {
   public InsertnewRecords(List<processemails__c> emaillist){
              insert emaillist;
        } 
}
```

How do I split emaillist in to batches of 200.

Comment: Can you show us the exception? Also, how big is your list? And how many records in that object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DML operation needs to be in the execute method:

```
public class InsertnewRecords implements Queueable {
    // Store all the records to process
    ProcessEmails__c[] recordsList;
    public InsertnewRecords(List<processemails__c> emaillist){
        recordsList = emailList;
    }
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        ProcessEmails__c[] temp = new ProcessEmails__c[0];
        // Grab up to 200 records
        while(!recordsList.isEmpty() && temp.size() < 200) {
            temp.add(recordsList.remove(0));
        }
        // If you might get errors, make sure you add error handling here
        insert temp;
        if(!recordsList.isEmpty()) {
            System.enqueueJob(this); // Do the next 200
        }
    }
}
```